# Streaming twitter with tweepy returns retweet_count always 0

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

My problem is that while streaming tweets with tweepy, `retweet_count` is always 0.

Here is my code:

```
tweet = utf8mb4.sub(u'', tweet.json)
tweet = json.loads(tweet)
print tweet

q = u'INSERT INTO url VALUES (%s, %s);'
for i in tweet['entities']['urls']:
    try:
        insert = (tweet['id'],
                    util.unshorten(i['expanded_url']))
        c.execute(q, insert)
    except IOError:
        continue



tweet['created_at'] = util.isoformat(tweet['created_at'])
tweet['text'] = htmlparser.unescape(tweet['text'])
tweet['source'] = util.strip_tags(tweet['source'])
q = u'INSERT IGNORE INTO status VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s);'
insert = (tweet['id'],
          tweet['user']['id'],
          tweet['created_at'],
          tweet['text'],
          tweet['source'],
          tweet['retweet_count'])
c.execute(q, insert)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite **normal** as it is expected when you are using streaming api endpoint, its because you receive the tweets as they are posted live on twitter platform, by the time you receive the tweet no other user had a chance to retweet it so retweet_count will always be 0.
If you want to find out the retweet_count you have to refetch this particular tweet some time later using the [rest api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) then you can see the retweet_count will contain the number of retweets happened till this particular point in time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a retweeted_status in json file, and that contains the real retweet_count

Comment: The retweeted_status contains a representation of the original tweet, it's not a count ([Tweets Field Guide](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets)).
@nickmilon has the right answer.